# Mudar o ícone do Excel

Tags: c#, c++, vba

Olá, começo me desculpando, não sou do C nem do C++, mas preciso muito de uma ajuda que pode ser dada tanto por quanto pelo outro, trabalho com soluções em Excel modelando a interface com XML, criei uma aplicação e estou usando um executável em C para abri-la, isso já corta aquela apresentação inicial da Microsoft Excel e o foco se volta para o meu sistema, mas eu gostaria de personalizar por completo, para isso, gostaria que o executável além de abrir a planilha também modificasse o seu ícone, para que o ícone que aparece na barra de tarefas seja o símbolo de minha aplicação, se alguém puder me ajudar fico muito grato, segue o código que usei para criar o executável:

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Reflection; 
using System.Threading; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 

static class Program 
{ 
// variáveis de instãncia 
static object oExcel = null; 
static object oBooks = null; 
static object oBook = null; 
static object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value; 
static System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture; 

[STAThread] 
static void Main() 
{ 
    string CaminhoDoArquivo = @"C:\Caminho\Para\Seu\Arquivo\Excel\ExcelComMacros.xlsm"; 

    if (ExcelEstaInstalado()) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(CaminhoDoArquivo)) 
            { 
                AbrirArquivo(CaminhoDoArquivo); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("O arquivo {0} não foi encontrado", CaminhoDoArquivo)); 
            } 
        } 
        catch (System.IO.IOException) 
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("Erro de acesso ao arquivo. Verifique o arquivo de configuração ou as permissões de pasta"); 
        } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Não foi possível encontrar a instalação do Microsoft Excel no seu computador"); 
    } 

    Application.Exit(); 
} 

private static void AbrirArquivo(string caminhoDoArquivo) 
{ 
    object oFileName = caminhoDoArquivo; 
    oExcel = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application")); 
    oExcel.GetType().InvokeMember("AutomationSecurity", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, oExcel, new object[] { 1 }, ci); 
    oExcel.GetType().InvokeMember("Visible", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, oExcel, new object[] { true }, ci); 
    oBooks = oExcel.GetType().InvokeMember("Workbooks", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, oExcel, null, ci); 
    oBook = oBooks.GetType().InvokeMember("Open", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, oBooks, new object[] { oFileName, oMissing, false }, ci); 
} 

public static bool ExcelEstaInstalado() 
{ 
    Type officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application"); 

    if (officeType == null) 
    { 
        return false; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return true; 
    } 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A melhor maneira seria vc criar um atalho da sua planilha, clicar com o lado direito do mouse ir em propriedades e alterar o ícone, quando vc invocar a planilha pelo c# vc vai dar o caminho do atalho,
Não tenho certeza se vai dar certo mas não custa tentar

Comment: Mudar o ícone do atalho não adianta pq o ícone original do Excel é que fica aparecendo na barra de tarefas, preciso de uma maneira de mudar o ícone original de forma que o ícone personalizado fique aparecendo na barra de tarefas.